# How to detect permission access of other apps?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-permissions, android-package-managers

I'm searching for a way to detect permission usage of other apps. The key idea is to detect, when other apps are accessing media or sensors (e.g. microphone).

I want to implement a service, which is looking for any permission usages, so that the service can inform the user, once any app is accessing the microphone or camera.

Does anybody know how to do this? I already found out, that I can read all granted permission of an app using the PackageManager, but I'm more interested in "real" permission usage.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think detecting permission requests isn't possible in that way. Since Android 6 rearranges permission system, there is no interest in proceeding this investigation.