# How to detect if any application requests the microphone in Android?

Tags: android, microphone

I'm developing an application that needs to know when other third party app requests the microphone.
Is there any way to detect it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After installing your app on your device, go check for permissions in settings->apps-> your app

Comment: I think this post should help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386823/how-to-get-manifest-permissions-of-any-installed-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

After some research, it seems to be impossible to know when another third party application requests the MICROPHONE due to security reasons.

If you want to perform actions according to actual state of the media recorder, you may have to handle that as explained in this post:

[How to detect if MediaRecorder is used by another application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049546/how-to-detect-if-mediarecorder-is-used-by-another-application)

And about detecting other apps permissions access, I think this can provide an answer: [How to detect permission access of other apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835839/how-to-detect-permission-access-of-other-apps)

But if you want to check apps that needs RECORD_AUDIO permission, you can continue reading the following lines:

Based on the answer of [Kopi-B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434175/kopi-b) at  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4386823/how-to-get-manifest-permissions-of-any-installed-android-app)

To get the list of apps requesting microphone you can then proceed as follows:

```java
 final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        final List pkgAppsList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);

        //create a package names list
        List<String> packageNames=new ArrayList<>();

        for (Object obj : pkgAppsList) {
            ResolveInfo resolveInfo = (ResolveInfo) obj;
            PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
            try {
                packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

            //check the microphone permission
            if (requestedPermissions!=null) {
                for (String packagePermission : requestedPermissions) {
                    if (packagePermission == Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) {
                        packageNames.add(packageInfo.packageName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but that I need is to know when any third party application ask for microphone to record audio.

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it works to help future readers

Comment: Your answer don't solve my problem. I need to know when any application request microphone to record audio, not if this application has permission to record audio

Comment: anh okay, great. let me update the answer accordingly. Thank you for clearance